# Software to improve audio output on windows

Tags: audio, windows-10

Comparing the audio output between two laptops I have, using the plug for headphones, one of them has a very dull sound.

Both are using win 10 and Realtek Hi Definition Audio.

Is there any application that can improve the audio quality of every sound? for example, youtube using a browser?

I tried Equalizer APO using Peace equalizer as an interface but I do not hear any difference.

Answer (score 1):

[AC3Filter](http://www.ac3filter.net/wiki/AC3Filter) - Not just for AC3 and DTS audio tracks. Also it can process any audio track, much of processing options allows to adjust the sound in almost any way. It is possible to upmix any audio source to 6 channels. Filter can do multi-channel and digital (SPDIF) output.

It's a bit old but [ffdshow-tryouts](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) (replaced by [Lav Filters](https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?p=1844890#post1844890)) certainly has a great set of filters and settings.

Don't forget that [adjustment to your settings in Windows](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/sound-quality-guide-windows-10/) should be your first step.